# Sumar valores de 2 tablas en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas con los mismos datos, una del año 2016 y otra del 2017, quiero hacer un query que me sume los datos de ambas tablas para hacer el total de los 2 años.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo para el ejemplo que cada uno de esos parámetros corresponden a un "Jugador", podria ser cualquier otro parámetro de agrupación.
La Query seria así, para sumar todas las Carreras Anotadas (CA) correspondientes a cada jugador.

### Query:

```
SELECT jugador,sum(CA) totalCA // Puedes agregar tantos sum como quieras
FROM
(
    SELECT jugador,CA // Puedes agregar tantos campos como quieras
    FROM 2016_table
    union all
    SELECT jugador,CA // Puedes agregar tantos campos como quieras
    FROM 2017_table
) t
GROUP BY jugador
```

> Aclaración: Para que el sum(x) sea coherente, debes tener los
>   parámetros en ambos los `SELECT` del `FROM` ( Uno de la tabla 2017 y otro
>   en la tabla 2016, como se ve con "CA")

Comment: Puedo agregar 14 columnas en ese Query?

Comment: Si, obviamente. No lo hice yo por temas de practicad al momento de escribir el ejemplo aquí mismo. Solo tienes que agregar los campos al SELECT del FROM y luego el sum() en el SELECT exterior, me explico?

Comment: Voy a intentarlo.

Comment: Me sale este error:  "error = Every derived table must have its own alias", puedo cerrar los select del union all en sub parentesis para ponerle un alias?

Comment: con este query me mostró algo "SELECT Jugador, sum(CA) totalCA FROM (SELECT jugador, CA FROM stats) as xxx union all (SELECT Jugador, CA FROM stats2017 as xxxx) " pero me tiraba todos los jugadores... asi que al final le puse un WHERE id = 6 (de un jugador en especifico) y no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

**En la primera tabla el valor de CA es 28 y en la otra es 3.**

He echo este query basado en lo que me sugeriste  `SELECT sum(CA) totalCA FROM (SELECT CA FROM stats WHERE id=6) as xxx union all (SELECT CA FROM stats2017 WHERE id=6)`

y me sale este resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no me sale la suma... que anda mal?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA RESUELTO. No me fije nunca el el alias t de el ejemplo.

```
 SELECT sum(CA) CA from (SELECT CA from stats WHERE id=6 union all SELECT CA FROM stats2017 where id = 6) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahora me interesa hacer formulas, ejemplo el promedio de bateo se calcula Hit entre turno, la formula segun las tablas seria **H/T**

En que lugar del query debo ponerlo? Me pierdo porque es sumando las 2 tablas y no una sola.

```
select sum(T) T, sum(CA) CA, sum(H) Hits, sum(2H) 2H, sum(3H) 3H, sum(HR) HR, sum(BB) BB, sum(SF) SF from ( select T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, BB, SF from stats where id=10 union all select T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, BB, SF from stats2017 where id=6 ) x
```